# Gemfire for storing BLOB

Tags: gemfire

We have a requirement where we want to store BLOB files in  GemFire. The estimated size of this region would be in TBs because of the BLOB files.
2 Approach we are planning to analyze. Please suggest

1) create the gemfire region with Overflow configuration. This should enable only Key in memory and actual data file overflowed to Gemfire diskstore.
   This will also help to control the GemFire region size.
   Size of Gemfire disk store however would be huge. Is this option feasible?

2) Store the files on Server disks with the file path stored in Gemfire region.
Use the file paths for directly accessing/updating the files from the client

any other suggested approach for such requirements?

Answer (score 0):

To me option 2 seems brittle. You would have a to do a lot of work to provide HA, handle disk failures, IO exceptions etc. Gemfire will take care of all these things if you use option 1.

What is the size of the blob you are looking to store? Gemfire will not be able to store a single value that is more than 2gb. Handling Terabytes of data in a region should not be a problem.

Comment: It will not be single large file but multiple  files each of say 20 Mb which will finally make size in TBs.

Comment: It will not be single large file but multiple  files each of say 20 Mb which will finally make size in TBs.  Second challenge is we just have 5 server nodes of 20 GB heap each. What type of region would be suggested - Partition?  My assumption is we will need to do Overflow becuase of limited servers and limited size. In case of situations like rebalancing is done will it not create a issue because of this huge region size during rebalancing.